# How to block specific keywords from searching on WordPress?

Tags: php, javascript, search

I'd like to block some specific banned keywords from searching on WordPress.
Or I'd like to show a redirect when someone search specific keywords.
How to do?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/). This action is run between the composition of a (search) query and the actual query, to allow you to change the query. So, it would allow you to intercept banned keywords like this:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse338558_intercept_banned_keywords' );
function wpse338558_intercept_banned_keywords ($query) {
  $banned = array ('word1','word2','word3');
  if (in_array ($query->query_vars['s'], $banned)) $query->s = '';
  }
```

Notes:

1. The above will simply empty the search, so there will be no feedback to the user. A hackish solution would be to use a very obscure search term like `jlwenuhrofslslfiehlserlisehrlilfheeipeueiq` and intercept that 404 to display a message.
2. The above will only intercept single keywords. If someone searches for two banned keywords at the same time he will get through. So you'll need a more elaborate condition to make this foolproof.

Comment: ok so how to redirect them to a custom page?

Comment: There are many ways to do this. If you follow the hack, you would intercept the query with the weird search string using `template_redirect`.

Answer (score 0):

To block specific keywords from appearing in search results on a WordPress website, you can use a plugin such as "Search Exclude" or "WP Search Block". Here are the steps to use "Search Exclude" plugin:

Go to your WordPress dashboard and navigate to "Plugins" → "Add New".
Search for "Search Exclude" plugin and install it.
After installation, activate the plugin.
Navigate to "Settings" → "Search Exclude" from the WordPress dashboard.
Enter the keywords that you want to block in the "Exclude Keywords" field, separated by commas.
Save the changes.
Now, when users search for any of the [blocked keywords](https://trendyport.com/how-to-check-if-your-wordpress-blog-posts-are-ranking-for-the-right-keywords/), they won't appear in the search results. If you want to unblock a keyword, simply remove it from the "Exclude Keywords" field in the plugin settings.