# Block internal search queries with pre_get_posts and regex rules

Tags: wp-query, search, pre-get-posts, regex, spam

**This relates to my previous question:** [Internal search spam](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/133116/site-gets-spammed-through-internal-search) (UPD: I no longer use Ivory Search)

**The closest question I found:** [Block search keywords](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/338558/how-to-block-specific-keywords-from-searching-on-wordpress)

As I understood, I need to use `pre_get_posts`, but I don't exactly know where it should go (functions.php?) and how I can create a regex-based rule to exclude everything that has "www." in it and non-Latin or non-numeric symbols like emojis and Cyrillic letters.

I have the results noindexed and blocked in robots.txt, but I'd like to fix the root of the problem if possible by stopping the queries from happening at all. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mentioned you use the Ivory search plugin in your other question but didn't mention it here. Any answer you get here will assume standard WP behaviour and may not work for you as a result of this plugin, you should ask their support routes of in their communities for help

Comment: Also as for where it should go, it's a general hook, it goes in any place that hooks can go, `functions.php` is a place it can go, as are plugins. As for the regex and cyrillic part, those aren't necessarily WP questions, you already have the `pre_get_posts` filter from the block search keywords question that checks a list of words, now you need generic PHP skills to match the query again regular expressions or to check for cyrillic characters, none of those are WordPress tasks or require WordPress knowledge to achieve

Comment: @TomJNowell I stopped using Ivory Search and switched to standard WP search. Thanks for the input, should I then create a separate question in the PHP section?